# App randomly crashes with a JSON error

Tags: json, python-3.x, error-handling

I've posted first the error message with full traceback and the code as well.

The code that is below is within a loop, that will run multiple times changing the variables within the session.get() link for the API data call.

From time to time I will get an error that the json.decoder.JSONDecodeError is expecting value... (full error below)

I can't figure out why.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\CarlosMiguel\Desktop\experiments\data_collector\data_collector.py", line 100, in <module>
get_data = session.get(api_data_link+symbol+"?limit=1000&period="+i).json()

File "C:\Users\CarlosMiguel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 892, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\CarlosMiguel\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "C:\Users\CarlosMiguel\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

File "C:\Users\CarlosMiguel\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Currently It's written like this (everything that needs to be is imported):

```
try:
    get_data = session.get(api_data_link+symbol+"?limit=1000&period="+i).json()
    for candle in get_data:
        #Do things with the requested data....


except:
    print("JSONError")
    print('Could not update data for')
    print(symbol + ' ' + i)
```

Could it be that the API just doesn't return anything on some random call?

Because it seems to be completely random when it crashes with that error.

If it could be the API just not returning anything, how could I write it to call it again for a few times, before continuing on with the rest of the app?

Comment: It looks like you are missing fundamental elements of the programming language. Start by learning the basics of python - there are plenty of courses, tutorials and documentation out there.

Comment: @MilosMrdovic there is literally nothing wrong with the code above.Can you elaborate? Otherwise your answer is the least helpful answer I've seen on Stackoverflow

Comment: If there is nothing wrong with the code, why are you asking this question? It is quite possible that the API returns bad or malformed response. In order to handle that you need to break that long chain of method calls and do some checks before calling .json() method. At least you can log the response and see exactly what response you are getting when those random errors occur.

Comment: @MilosMrdovic great, thanks. That's the type of answer I was looking for. ;) The code above works just fine 99 out of 100 times. That is why I'm thinking the API reposnse is what's wrong.